# What does 'context string for the given token' mean?

Tags: c++, tokenize

I'm writing a tokenizer assignment (in c++) based on the nand2tetris course and part of the assignment requires a context string. I'm not sure what is meant by this and I'm looking for a breakdown or some kind of pseudo/example code to illustrate what it means.
(I feel like it's a case of staring at a shelf looking for a book that's right in front of you but you can't see because you've been looking for so long!)

The instructions are:

> Generate a context string for the given token. It shows the line
>   before the token, the line containing the token, and a line with a ^
>   marking the token's position. Tab stops are every 8 characters in the
>   context string, tabs are replaced by spaces (1 to 8) so that the next
>   character starts on an 8 character boundary.

I know this is probably a case of obvious English not code, but I'm just a little lost and any help would be legendary as I'm still super basic where programming is concerned.

I was thinking something like:

```
string token_context(Token token)
{
    return "previous line \n" + "token" + "somehow having 8 spaces and the ^ symbol where the token is" ;
}
```

Comment: you may find it helpful to review the usage of strtok(), an old c function for tokenizing tokens from a c style string.  See for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok.  Please note that strtok maintains internal state as it is called in a loop.  I really am not sure what the assignment is asking, but it may have something similar to this function?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into that but apparently strtok isn't used in this as we have to read the input character by character, not as a string, so there are no delimiters from my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please compile and run this code.  I think it will demonstrate the use of the tabs and spaces as explained by @Jonathan Geisler.

Please note that on your professor's system, it is assumed that tabs take up 8 spaces.  However, on my system, they output a 4 space width.  So, I have a constant defined as tab_spaces set to 8.  If you find the carat is not in the right place, change that constant to 4 and try again.

Examine the output in your debugger, and I think it will be clear.

```
Output:

int index = 10;
if(index < 8 & index % 2 == 1) {
             ^
```

Process finished with exit code 0

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Token {
    string prior_line;
    string token_line;
    string token;
    size_t token_offset;
    size_t token_length;
};

const size_t tab_spacing{8};   // this has to be '4' on my system
string token_context(Token token)
{
  size_t tab_count = 0;
  size_t space_count = 0;

  string return_string{token.prior_line};  // 1st line: prior line
  return_string += "\n";                   // end of line 1,

  return_string += token.token_line;  // 2nd line, the one with the token
  return_string += "\n";              // end of line 2,

  // calculate tabs and spaces for line 3
  tab_count = token.token_offset / tab_spacing;  // tabs to get to token offset
  space_count = token.token_offset % tab_spacing;  // spaces to get to token offset

  // Build the 3rd line of the context string by inserting tabs
  for(size_t i = 0; i < tab_count; i++) {
    return_string += "\t";
  }

  // now insert the spaces
  for(size_t i = 0; i < space_count; i++) {
    return_string += " ";
  }
  // now, add the carat '^'
  return_string += "^";

  return_string += "\n";
  return return_string;
}

int main()
{
  string str1 = "int index = 10;";
  string str2 = "if(index < 8 & index % 2 == 1) {";
  size_t token_offset = 13;
  size_t token_length = 1;
  string token_str = "&";

  Token token;
  token.prior_line = str1;
  token.token_line = str2;
  token.token_offset = token_offset;
  token.token = token_str;
  token.token_length = token_length;

  std::cout << token_context(token) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Just saw your comment and started to add the class definitions we have. I'll have a look and see in relation to the code provided and see how I can tweak it. Thanks for the code version of the explanation :) I've added the classes below incase you were interested (sorry it's in random parts, there are too many characters but the below is a single class and the above is a single class :) )

Comment: using namespace std ;
using namespace Assignment_Tokeniser ;

// token_is_in test
void token_is_in_test(Token token,TokenKind kind)
{
    cout << "token_is_in(token," << token_kind_to_string(kind) << ") returns " ;
    cout << (token_is_in(token,kind) ? "true" : "false") ;
    cout << endl;
}

Comment: // this main program tokenises standard input and
// prints the tokens as they are found
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    Token token ;
    int count = 0 ;

    // remember and display each token as it is read
    token = next_token() ;
    while ( token_kind(token) != tk_eoi )
    {
        // output context every 4 tokens

Comment: if ( ++count % 4 == 0 )
        {
            cout << token_context(token) << endl ;
            token_is_in_test(token,tk_identifier) ;
            token_is_in_test(token,tk_integer) ;
            token_is_in_test(token,tk_double) ;
            token_is_in_test(token,tk_keyword) ;
            token_is_in_test(token,tk_symbol) ;
        }

Comment: cout << token_to_string(token) << endl ;
        token = next_token() ;
    }
    cout << "read " << count << " tokens" << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}

Answer (score 2):

Think of the context string like you see with compiler error messages.  The context string is used to show what is surrounding the token, or its context.  The problem is asking for something three lines:

1. The line of text that immediately proceeds the line with the token in it.
2. The line of text containing the token it.
3. A line with a `^` in it.  The placement of the `^` should be underneath the actual token.

The stuff about the tabs is to help you get the `^` in the right place.  Basically, it is saying that a tab acts like a variable number of spaces.  The number of spaces a tab acts like makes the next character be on a multiple of 8.  For example `"ab\tc"` should be thought of as the same as `"ab      c"` because the tab character (`\t`) was at the third space and so it acted like 6 spaces so that the `c` would be in the eighth position of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the break down Jonathan, I think I get what the task means (especially regarding the tab and spacing deal - very much thank you for that part!) but I'm stll unclear what this would look like in practice/code wise.

Comment: @DNM: Do you have a class definition for Token that you could post?

Comment: @Gardener the class definitions I have are in two parts:

Comment: #include "tokeniser.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;
using namespace Assignment_Tokeniser ;

// this main program tokenises standard input and
// prints the tokens as they are found
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    Token token ;
    int count = 0 ;

    // remember and display each token as it is read
    token = next_token() ;
    while ( token_kind(token) != tk_eoi )
    {
        cout << token_to_string(token) << endl ;
        token = next_token() ;
        count++ ;
    }
    cout << "read " << count << " tokens" << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}